# When using a likelihood ratio test to test for significance of a main effect, should I use the most maximal or minimal model as a base model?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, likelihood-ratio

Lets suppose I have a set of n covariates, and I want to test for the significance of the main effect of covariate i. I want to do this using a likelihood ratio test; fitting a model with covariate i included, and also a "base" model with covariate i not included.

My question is this: when doing the likelihood ratio test, should my base model be as maximal as possible by including all other covariates along with interactions? Or should I be fitting the most minimal, intercept-only model, and adding only covariate i onto the base model instead?